# Search value "in_array"

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I have this array

```
Array
(
    [result] => Array
        (
            [status] => nok
            [reason] => Character not found.
        )

    [code] => 404
    [content_type] => application/json;charset=utf-8
)
```

I want to check the [status], if it is "nok" it should appear "Match found".

My code:

```
$info = $r['result']['status'];
if (in_array("nok", $info))
  {
  echo "Match found";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Match not found";
  }
?>
```

Comment: `$r['result']['status']` this is not an array . u can chk like `if($info == 'nok')`

Comment: `if (in_array("nok", $info)){` needs to be `if ($info === "nok"){`

Comment: $r['result']['status'] this is not array this is a key of an array.

Comment: or `if (in_array("nok", $r['result'])){` you can use this too

Comment: `if (in_array("nok", $info)){` needs to be `if ($info === "nok"){`  or `if (in_array("nok", $r['result'])){` you can use this too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the function [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) check if the value exists in an array, you don't give an array but a string.

You have two options:

change you code to this:

```
if (isset($r['result']) && in_array("nok", $r['result'])) { //add isset to not raise a warning when it doesn't exists
```

Or if the result is always the same you can do this:

```
if (isset($r['result']['status']) && $r['result']['status'] === 'nok') {   //add isset to not raise a warning when it doesn't exists
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case:

```
 $r['result']['status']
```

is not an array but a string.

So you can ask for:

```
if(in_array("nok", $r['result']))
```

or

```
if($r['result']['status'] == "nok")
```

Comment: That is funny! Less than one minute apart, and the same answer :-)

Comment: Easy question! - Everybody wants to answer.

Answer (score 0):

$info is not an array, it's a string.  Try this instead:

```
if (in_array("nok", $r['result']))
{
   echo "Match found";
}
else
{
   echo "Match not found";
}
```

Or

```
if ($r['result']['status'] == "nok"){
```

Comment: You should use isset so you won't raise a warning when it doesn't exists

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `in_array` in this code. [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) searches a linear array for string values... so this is how you would use it:

```
$arr = array("dog", "cat", "mouse");
if(in_array("mouse", $arr)) echo "Eek, a mouse!";
```

You can just compare using normal logic since you are comparing a string to a string:

```
$info = $r['result']['status'];
if ($info == "nok")
  {
  echo "Match found";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Match not found";
  }
```

Comment: Don't use <? since this is not always available: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php